# Can't send token with request with ng-token-auth/devise-token-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, authentication, devise

I'm working through a great tutorial by which can be found here: https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails written by 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/199712/jason-swett.

I'm trying to figure out why I can't send a request with a token in the header on sign_in. My user registration call works great and a new user gets created in the db, but when I try to log in, no token is sent.

Here's my index.coffee

```
angular.module 'angDomino', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'rails', 'ng-token-auth']
  .config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $authProvider) ->
    $authProvider.configure({
      apiUrl: '/api'
      })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
      })
    $stateProvider
      .state "home",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/views/main.html",
        controller: "MainCtrl"
      .state "groups",
        url: "/groups",
        templateUrl: "app/views/groups.html",
        controller: "GroupsCtrl"
      .state "sign_in",
        url: "/sign_in",
        templateUrl: "app/views/user_sessions/new.html",
        controller: "UserSessionsCtrl"
      .state "sign_up",
        url: "/sign_up",
        templateUrl: "app/views/user_registrations/new.html",
        controller: "UserRegistrationsCtrl"

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

  .factory "Group", (RailsResource) ->
    class Group extends RailsResource
      @configure url: "/api/groups", name: "group"
```

Here's the registration request header:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:158
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
If-Modified-Since:0
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/sign_up
```

And the registration response:

```
access-token:ZAC77KtVm_BBXExMiF5Okg
cache-control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
client:AqyOPNCBIiufWAZqTkIPZg
connection:close
content-length:240
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Tue, 28 Apr 2015 23:38:58 GMT
etag:"e190da3eab4b3b2da0d6dc8257fd6d91"
expiry:1431473938
server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
token-type:Bearer
uid:cc0e37ab-f891-4334-a887-c0a71903edf9
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-request-id:8bf9fe8a-73b9-4e3d-ad40-c8574e88e7c3
x-runtime:0.272364
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

The sign out works perfectly (req header):

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
access-token:0PSupG02KwsbU6k1nQuTXQ
Cache-Control:max-age=0
client:AqyOPNCBIiufWAZqTkIPZg
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:auth_headers=%7B%22access-token%22%3A%220PSupG02KwsbU6k1nQuTXQ%22%2C%22token-type%22%3A%22Bearer%22%2C%22client%22%3A%22AqyOPNCBIiufWAZqTkIPZg%22%2C%22expiry%22%3A%221431474351%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22d1871d3d-a8a9-437a-88b9-e0a43f5896da%22%7D
DNT:1
expiry:1431474351
Host:localhost:9000
If-Modified-Since:0
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/sign_up
token-type:Bearer
uid:d1871d3d-a8a9-437a-88b9-e0a43f5896da
```

But when I try to login with that same email/pwd, I get:

General

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/auth/sign_in
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:43
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
If-Modified-Since:0
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/sign_in
```

Does anybody know why the login won't send the token?
Here's my user_sessions controller (in coffeescript):

```
angular.module('angDomino').controller 'UserSessionsCtrl', [
  '$scope'
  ($scope) ->
    $scope.$on 'auth:login-error', (ev, reason) ->
      $scope.error = reason.errors[0]
      return
    return
]
```

Here are the complete sign_in headers:

```
General
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/auth/sign_in
Request Method:POST
Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Response Headers
view source
cache-control:no-cache
connection:close
content-length:59
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Thu, 07 May 2015 12:53:46 GMT
server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08)
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-request-id:480b63c1-1415-4c49-8774-ccfc11eee644
x-runtime:0.005285
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:43
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9000
If-Modified-Since:0
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/sign_in
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
    view source
    {email: "b@b.com", password: "1234567890"}
    email: "b@b.com"
    password: "1234567890"
```

Here's the dev.log for sign_up:

```
Started POST "/api/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-07 07:40:18 -0500
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"b@b.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:9000/sign_up", "config_name"=>"default"}
Unpermitted parameters: confirm_success_url, config_name
Unpermitted parameters: confirm_success_url, config_name
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (1.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = 'email' AND "users"."email" = 'b@b.com'[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (2.9ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmed_at", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "provider", "tokens", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["confirmed_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.475118"], ["created_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.475466"], ["email", "b@b.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$7dSKnalwMHcuTrWSDEbLSen85tzA9DEyH.Q.EnxHllwZeNOdvBUMy"], ["provider", "email"], ["tokens", "{}"], ["uid", "b@b.com"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.475466"]]
  [1m[36m (79.9ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "confirmed_at" = $1, "tokens" = $2, "uid" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 2[0m  [["confirmed_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.638115"], ["tokens", "{\"wASSQpP_tjVaK-VoROXwHg\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$aJFJmimoQNQFz3T9rItGwOzHMRwtuENcBhZdVCC2b0GBsinKgIhuC\",\"expiry\":1432212018}}"], ["uid", "9ae44b7b-3f7a-4f2d-9091-4cc779751355"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.638237"]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[36mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "confirmed_at" = $1, "tokens" = $2, "uid" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 2[0m  [["confirmed_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.712254"], ["tokens", "{\"wASSQpP_tjVaK-VoROXwHg\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$nb1iyRMzNgjvi34tMK5Ysers4IOulvviMJSA5Q8uop5ARuXMOtxDa\",\"expiry\":1432212018,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$aJFJmimoQNQFz3T9rItGwOzHMRwtuENcBhZdVCC2b0GBsinKgIhuC\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-05-07T07:40:18.711-05:00\"}}"], ["uid", "95b1c932-b763-4f32-b441-0968175575d5"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-07 12:40:18.712496"]]
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 363ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 90.3ms)


Started GET "/api/auth/validate_token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-07 07:44:29 -0500
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController#validate_token as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."uid" = '95b1c932-b763-4f32-b441-0968175575d5' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE[0m  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "confirmed_at" = $1, "tokens" = $2, "uid" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["confirmed_at", "2015-05-07 12:44:29.561416"], ["tokens", "{\"wASSQpP_tjVaK-VoROXwHg\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$7zZRRlJ3rvIS0H/jQUITB.4kEQfdENDB92uCDf84EXsF93V5EzIFS\",\"expiry\":1432212269,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$nb1iyRMzNgjvi34tMK5Ysers4IOulvviMJSA5Q8uop5ARuXMOtxDa\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-05-07T07:44:29.560-05:00\"}}"], ["uid", "c9719276-a107-41f7-868f-9ed8c87cfa3a"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-07 12:44:29.561612"]]
  [1m[36m (1.2ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Completed 200 OK in 144ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

And here is the dev.log for sign_in:

```
Started POST "/api/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-07 07:53:46 -0500
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"b@b.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.5ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (uid='b@b.com' AND provider='email')  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

Comment: I believe it's normal for sign-in not to be sending a token. My understanding is that the sign-in response should supply you with a token which you'll use for all subsequent requests, but not the first one. Seems like sign-in is not happening successfully for whatever reason. Can you give us more details on the `/sign_in` response, like headers and payload? And maybe keep an eye on your Rails log when the sign-in request fires off?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I edited the post to add the complete sign_in headers and the dev.log. Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: Can you double-check that your user's `email` and `uid` are both b@b.com, and that you're using the right password? And maybe try the call in Postman instead of the web?

Comment: You know as long as I've been looking at the docs for each of these tools, I didn't realize that it's expecting the uid to be the email address. No that's not what the uid is.

Comment: Okay, see what happens when they match and let me know. :)

Comment: Do you know how to configure it to make it search by email instead of uid? I couldn't find it here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#configuration-cont

Comment: Seems to me like it would be easier to first make the uid match the email and see if that works. Then if that works, look into the solution that involves traversing a little more mysterious path.

Comment: Ah yep. That worked. I changed the model to: self.uid = self.email instead of what the tutorial had: self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid and that fixed it. I would eventually like to enable fb/twitter login. Any idea on how to figure out why it expects the uid to be an email?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I'm curious about that one myself.

Comment: Ok I'll check into it. Thanks for your help @JasonSwett!

Comment: Hello everybody, I didn't understand how to changed the model. If I try to find out self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid I found anything. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, at least at this point in time, you have to make your user's `uid` match your user's `email`.